# How to iterate through a 2d vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, vector

I have a 2d vector of size 7*7 named table.

All of the values are 0 except for 2 of them.

When I run the following program, I am assuming I enter an infinite loop because nothing outputs to the screen and I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to cancel in the terminal.

Currently I have this, which is giving me the error

```
for(x=0; x = 6 ; x++){
    for(y=0; y = 6 ; y++){
        if (table.at(x).at(y) != 0)
            cout << "Yes." << endl;             
        }
    }
```

I am not seeing why it doesn't go through each value of the table, in the order (0,0) then (0,1) then (0,2) ... (1,) (1,1) (1,2) ... etc until it goes through all them.

Comment: Feel like an idiot. Thank you sir.

Comment: It happens now and then to every programmer. Don't take it too hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `=` with `<=`

```
for(x=0; x <= 6 ; x++){
  for(y=0; y <= 6 ; y++){
    if (table.at(x).at(y) != 0)
      cout << "Yes." << endl;
    else
      cout << "No." << endl;  
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow. You just solved an hour of racking my brain with one character. Thank you sir.